# Chrome extension navigate to URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension in which I already have an HTML file with several anchors and am trying to make Chrome open a new tab with that URL when clicked.

For that purpose, I have `"permissions": ["tabs"]` in my `manifest.json` and

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': event.target.href})
})
```

in my JS file; but that is just not working. What could I be missing?

Regards,
mto

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm still new trying to learn about formatting :)

Comment: Please use the search function. An identical question was asked 2 days ago.

Comment: I don't get it ... how do you expect the browser action icon to know about the href of an HTML element you clicked "some time before" the browser action icon??

Comment: @devnull69 the icon opens up an HTML file with several anchors it in.

Comment: @nietonfir can you throw me a link?

Comment: Yes ... this would be the default popup, I suppose? Inside the popup Javascript code, you should bind an event handler to the anchor elements (see my answer below)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see `this.href`

Comment: To answer what is wrong with your code above: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is fired in the background script, if and only if there is no popup to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I usually do it (example: Clicking on a link in popup.html)

**popup.html**

```
<a href="http://whereever.you.go.com/whatever.html" class="clickme">Click</a>
```

**popup.js**

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
   chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href')});
});
```

or vanilla Javascript (every element with class `clickme` is an anchor)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   var theAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName('clickme');
   for(i=0, len=theAnchors.length; i<len; i++) {
      theAnchors[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
         chrome.tabs.create({url: this.href});
      }, false);
   }
}, false);
```

Comment: This is really funny. I have the following HTML and JS and URL seems to do nothing when I click on it. 
    <a class="url"     
    href="mysu.sabanciuniv.edu/en/purchasing/">Purchasing</a>

    document.getElementByClassName('url')[0].onclick = function() {    
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': event.target.href}); };

Comment: event.target is undefined. `event` is only defined as a global object in Internet Explorer, in Chrome you'd have to provide the event object as a parameter to the event handler `onclick = function(e) {... e.target ...}`

Comment: ... or you'd rather use DOM2 event listeners like `element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...}, false)`

Comment: Not meaning to start a flame war, but `event.target` worked on http://jsfiddle.net/6kf46/6/ and in Chrome.

Comment: I am really, really going nuts. I applied the code you gave me and and no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. Below is the full code:
`element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': this.href});
};`

I wonder if I should add a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {`

Comment: wow ... since when is Chrome using the vintage IE specific global `event` object??? I never stop learning, I suppose. I agree that your fiddle is working for me too (Chrome 34 Win). I wasn't expecting that

Comment: Yes, you should use something like a `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to make sure that the `element` already exists when you try to bind the event listener to it

Comment: @devnull69 You should edit your answer to include those wrappers.

Comment: ... see my latest edit. I included the load event listener and a loop to bind event handlers to every anchor with a specific class. There is no `e` or `event`, you can use `this` to easily refer to the current element

Comment: @devnull69 FYI, what didn't work before is now working (theAnchor stuff) Thanks :) I don't know how it happened but it did. Maybe the lack of the line `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...});` caused that?

Answer (score 2):

At last I was able to do it.

The code I needed was:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': event.target.href});
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot to those who even attempted to help :)

Regards,
K.

Comment: And what happens if the click goes, for instance, on the `<body>` element?

Comment: That's a very good question @Xan, do you have a suggestion? Maybe wrap each URL in a separate div?

Comment: I'd say - use jQuery, `$('a').click(function(e){/*...*/});` to bind to all links (and only links) at the same time.

Comment: @Xan I've tried your suggestion, and regretted to see it doesn't work :S This is my code as it is now:
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $.('a').click(function(e) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': event.target.href});
  });
});`

Regards,

Comment: @Xan By "it doesn't work", I mean that nothing happens when I click on any URLs.

Comment: And where, tell me, is `event` defined in your code?

Comment: You mean `var event = foo`?

Comment: Try using the supplied `e` event object instead of `event`. Also, are you properly debugging your extension? See the guide [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) to hunt for easy errors.

Comment: I have got next to no experience on Javascript, so can you please clarify? I've already got `$('a').click(function(e)`, so maybe you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite using jQuery, that I hinted at in comments to another answer:

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready, jQuery-style:
$(document).ready( function() {
  // Bind a click handler to all <a> elements:
  $('a').click( function(e) {
    // Event is passed into the handler as parameter "e"
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': e.target.href});
  });
});
```